# Is this response properly encoded?

Tags: http, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

I am receiving the following headers in response to a web request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
...
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
...


Ÿ’âýÝ©ËIJ‹sç
ÿ-
// in hex the encoded data reads:
// 00000000  9f 92 e2 fd dd a9 cb 49 4a 8b 73 e7 0a ff 02 2d          IJ s    -
```

Question:

1. Is this a valid or properly encoded chunked response? I don't see any 0 length chunks in there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

No, this does not seem to be properly encoded. In general, the commonly used [chunked transfer encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1) has the following scheme:

```
<chunk-size> <CRLF>
<chunk-data> <CRLF>
<chunk-size> <CRLF>
<chunk-data> <CRLF>
⋮
<chunk-size> <CRLF>
<chunk-data> <CRLF>
0 <CRLF>
<CRLF>
```

The *chunk-size* is a string of hex digits indicating the size of the following *chunk-data*, both terminated by a CRLF sequence. The chunked encoding is ended by any chunk whose size is zero which is terminated by an empty line.